# Trying to keep filled bars in a faceted plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have this plot:

```
ggplot(data.PE5, aes(ybands,fill=factor(decide))) + geom_bar(position="dodge")
```

which produces: 
[image]

Then I want to facet by a factor, creating two stacked plots w/ dodged, colored bars

```
ggplot(data.PE5, aes(ybands,fill=factor(decide))) + geom_bar(position="dodge") + 
facet_grid(~group_label)
```

However, I lose the factor-based coloring, which I want to keep:

[image]

Comment: What's the result of str(data.PE5)?
A similar example below works just fine, and the colours are retained also in the facet plot.

ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl,fill=factor(am))) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", binwidth = 1) +
  facet_grid(~gear)

Answer (score 2):

If you move the `fill` into the `geom_bar` it should work.  As:

```
ggplot(data.PE5, aes(ybands)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=factor(decide)),position="dodge") + facet_grid(~group_label)
```

The reason is the way `ggplot2` builds plots as a grammar (I think).

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that - it doesn't matter where you set the fill aesthetic as long as that particular layer inherits or sets it.  A reproducible example would be helpful...